# Sql Query to get the parent task name in the child task row

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table that contains this type of info.
In this entry id is used as a unique id and ind_id is '0' if it doesn't have a parent task and if ind_id content a value it mentioned a entry_id of the parent task.
Example table below.

```
entry_id | task            | ind_id | date
------------------------------------------------
1000     | example_1       | 0      | 22-08-2020
1012     | example_3       | 1000   | 22-08-2020
1013     | example_4       | 1000   | 22-08-2020
1004     | example_1_14    | 0      | 22-08-2020
1006     | example_2_4     | 1004   | 22-08-2020
1007     | example_8_4     | 1006   | 22-08-2020
1010     | example_4_1     | 0      | 22-08-2020
```

I would like to get the data like this.

```
entry_id | task            | ind_id |parent_task_name| date
--------------------------------------------------------------
1000     | example_1       | 0      |null            | 22-08-2020
1012     | example_3       | 1000   |example_1       | 22-08-2020
1013     | example_4       | 1000   |example_1       | 22-08-2020
1004     | example_1_14    | 0      |null            | 22-08-2020
1006     | example_2_4     | 1004   |example_1_14    | 22-08-2020
1010     | example_4_1     | 0      |null            | 22-08-2020
```

Would anyone help me to find a solution for this?

Answer (score 1):

This looks like a `JOIN`:

```
select e.*,
       ep.task as parent_task_name
from entries e left join
     entries ep
     on ep.entry_id = e.ind_id
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this query

```
select a.entry_id,a.task,a.ind_id,
(select task from table_name where entity_id = a.ind_id) as
 parent_task_name,a.date from table_name;
```

Answer (score 0):

Using Hierarchical queries in Oracle(since DB is not tagged):

```
WITH CTE1 AS (
SELECT TASK, CONNECT_BY_ROOT ENTRY_ID AS root_id FROM TABLE1 A
START WITH IND_ID = 0
CONNECT BY PRIOR IND_ID = ENTRY_ID)
SELECT A.*, B.TASK AS PARENT_TASK_NAME FROM TABLE1 A LEFT OUTER JOIN CTE1 B
ON (A.IND_ID = B.ROOT_ID) 
ORDER BY A.TASK, A.IND_ID;
```